# Rails Disposable Object in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, controller, ruby-hash

Trying to store objects in an array to iterate through in the view.

In my controller:

```
def expire
  @search = Search.new(search_params)
  if @search.valid?
    @clients = []
    @allClients = #value from REST API
    @allClients.each do |client|
      @clientele = Clientele.new
      @clientele["exp"] = client.experience  ##Also tried @clientele.exp = client.experience
      @clientele["email"] = client.email  ##Also tried @clientele.email = client.email
      @clients.push(@clientele)
    end
  end
end
class Clientele
  def exp
  end
  def email
  end
end
```

In my view nothing shows up and showing the @clients array gives an empty array:

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
  <%= client.exp %>
  <%= client.email %>
<% end %>
<%= clients %> #=> []
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I can't seem to just create a temporary object to store values in and store it into an array. Any help or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `@allClients` (at least in the code you provided). So, `@allClients` is `nil` and `@allClients.each` produces nothing.

Try something more like:

```
def expire
  @search = Search.new(search_params)
  if @search.valid?
    @clients = Client.all.map do |client|
      Clientele.new(
        exp: client.experience,
        email: client.email
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Using `map` returns an `Array` populated by the result of the block (which is an initialized `Clientele` object).

Are you going to add some more code in? I assume you are. Because, as currently written, the whole `Clientele` instantiation thing seems kind of pointless.

You can make your Clientele class like this:

```
class Clientele

  def initialize(params={})
    params.each do |k,v|
      class_eval{attr_accessor k}
      send("#{k}=",v)
    end
  end

end
```

And then you'll be able to instantiate it the way I show. The `class_eval` bit creates the getters and setters. The `send` bit assigns the passed-in parameters to their respective variables.

If you want to skip the `Clientele` class altogether, you could do:

```
def expire
  @search = Search.new(search_params)
  if @search.valid?
    @clients = Client.all.map do |client|
      {exp: client.experience, email: client.email}
    end
  end
end
```

In which case you'll need to change your `erb` to:

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
  <%= client[:exp] %>
  <%= client[:email] %>
<% end %>
<%= clients %> #=> []
```

Or, if you like your erb the way it is, you could do:

```
def expire
  @search = Search.new(search_params)
  if @search.valid?
    @clients = Client.all.map do |client|
      OpenStruct.new(exp: client.experience, email: client.email)
    end
  end
end
```

In which case, you can still do:

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
  <%= client.exp %>
  <%= client.email %>
<% end %>
<%= clients %> #=> []
```

Comment: I was trying to dumb down my code to make it easier to understand what I was trying to do. I'm using a REST api that gives me an array of clients, each with a list of definitions/items.

Comment: `Clientele.new` gives me a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error. :(

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see that bit about your `Clientele` class in your OP. I'll update.

Comment: Can I create an object without creating a class for it?

Comment: Here's a quick [post](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2010/05/12/quickie-objects-in-ruby/) on Quicky Objects in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this all out.